# Question based on probability( did not understand the solution)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

An urn contains $5$ white and $8$ black balls. Two successive drawings of $3$ balls at a time are made such that balls are not replaced before the second draw. Find the probability that first draw gives $3$ white balls and second draw gives $3$ black balls.

How to do this one? Can anyone give me a detailed explanation for this one?

In the solution it has been given that

$A=$ Drawing $3$ white balls

$B=$ Drawing 3 black balls

I did not understand from this step

$P(A \cap B)= P(A)P(B \mid A)$

When do we use this formula?

$P(A)$ comes out to be= $5/143$

After drawing $3$ white balls in first draw, $10$ balls are left, out of which $8$ are black balls.

$P(B \mid A)= 8C3/10C3=7/15$

Required probability= $7/15 \cdot 5/143$

Please explain me this solution.

Comment: The conditional probability formula: The probability that $A$ and $B$ happen is the product that $A$ happens times the probabality that $B$ happens, given that $A$ happened. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability

Answer (score 3):

$P(A) = \frac{\binom{5}{3}}{\binom{13}{3}}$ by standard ball counting. ($3$ out of the $5$ possible whites, while there are $3$ out of $13$ total ways).

By definition of the conditional probability $$P(B|A) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$$
from which your formula follows by multiplying both sides by $P(A)$. In this case it is quite intuitive: for $A$ and $B$ to both happen, first $A$ has to happen with chance $P(A)$ and then *given that* $A$ already happened, we need $P(B|A)$ to know what the chance of $B$ now is, and we mutiply these. We cannot easily compute $P(B)$ without any knowledge on what happened in the first draw, because the first draw affects the available balls in draw 2.

But given that $A$ happened we have $2$ white balls and $8$ black balls left for draw 2. So then the chance of $3$ blacks is $P(B|A) = \frac{\binom{8}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}}$. (Now we have $10$ balls in total, $8$ of which are black and we draw $3$ balls).

Comment: You meant to say "from which your formula follows by multiplying both sides by $P(A)$."

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thx. I've edited (you could have too, I don't mind)